# spyder crash after installed PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, spyder

Why the spyder and Ipython is crash after  pip install PyQt4 whl from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4 ? It showed that no response when double click spyder or Ipython icons. 
I have try several times in Windows 7, used Winpython,version is python 3.6. 
Though the spyder is broken, the python default shell could import PyQt4 modules. Maybe the PyQt4 conflict with spyder?

Comment: Please use PyQt5 instead of PyQt4. Spyder should work with PyQt4, but those bindings are quite outdated by now.

Answer (score 1):

hum, if you try to get it run with PyQt4, maybe "pip uninstall PyQt5", and even remove directory "python-3.6.4.amd64\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5" manually after that.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience if you have Spyder 3 and both PyQt4 and PyQt5 libraries installed this causes problems launching Spyder and thats why it is crashing. Either try updating Spyder 3 to Spyder 4 or uninstall PyQt5.

Comment: There is no reason why you would downgrade PyQt versions. Just upgrade and wave PyQt4 to the archive.